# How to create angular 2 component in vaadin grid custom renderer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I'm new into Angular 2.
I want to ask how to instantiate component dynamicaly.

I have created angular 2 component `XyComponent` with some inputs and some outputs (events).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'xy',
  templateUrl: 'xy.component.pug',
  styleUrls: ['xy.component.scss'],
})
export class XyComponent {
  @Input()
  public x: any = null;

  @Output('xyEvent')
  xyEventEmitter: EventEmitter<XyEvent> = new EventEmitter<XyEvent>();

  constructor(myElementRef: ElementRef) {}

  getElementRef() { return myElementRef; }
}
```

The component is working fine when is used in compiled angular template using its directive `<xy></xy>`.

In another `XyView` component I'm using `vaadin-grid` to display tabular data. I have lot of rows so I'm reading data to grid through a function.

```
<vaadin-grid id="grid" [items]="itemsFunction"></vaadin-grid>
```

I want one column to have a special renderer and use `XyComponent` in that column. I have set the renderer up:

```
// in XyView component:
this.grid = document.querySelector('#grid');

this.grid.columns[column.index].renderer = (cell: any) => {

  // ... how to create an XyComponent instance and pass it to grid ?

}
```

When the renderer is creating simple text into `cell.element.textContent` or simple html into `cell.element.innerHTML` all is working fine.

I have tryed to instantiate component programaticaly:

```
this.grid.columns[column.index].renderer = (cell: any) => {

  let xy = new XyComponent(null); // ? don't know the root element of cell
  xy.x = 'AAA';
  let subscription = xy.xyEventEmitter.subscribe(
    event => console.log("xyEvent fired"),
    error => console.log("xyEvent error"),
    () => console.log("xyEvent finished")
  );

  cell.element = xy;
  // cell.element = xy.getMyElementRef();
  // cell.element = xy.getMyElementRef().nativeElement;

}
```

but none of these have worked.

How should I create component instance to render properly into grid ?